# Problem when i get data from database with varchar and assign it to database again in date

Tags: php, sql

i have a problem when i get data from database and the data type is varchar255 and after that i want to assign it that to datetime but when i see the data its 1970-01-01 07:00 but i should 2020-05-30 22:38

```
    $formula = trim($config['feature_setdays_prem']);
    $formula = antiject($formula);
    $formula = str_replace("$", "", $formula);
    $endtime = date("Y-m-d g:i", strtotime('+'.$formula. ' days'));
```

```
$config['feature_setdays_prem']
```

this config is from database data type varchar255 and the value is 7, and i want to assign to sql like this

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_UserStatus (id,Status,DTStartPrem,DTEndPrem,Cash) VALUES ('$username', '2', '$starttime', '$endtime', '50000')"
```

its always 1970. but when i echo its 2020-05-30. i dont know what happen.

Answer (score 0):

solved already by myself.

Answer : i use 2 flow,

send the parameter config throught function and call in another class.